# What is the meaning of '@' symbol in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, syntax

What is the `@` symbol mean in [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle)?

For example:

```
select * from question_answer@abcd where id = '45'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It refers to a non-local table, the bit behind the @ is the db descriptor.

```
select * from question_answer@abcd where id = '45'
```

Means select not from the local `question_answer` table, but from the table on the db designated as `abcd`. The keyword to google for is `dblink`

Answer (score 16):

This is the syntax for accessing a table via a database link called "abcd"
See the documentation for [CREATE DATABASE LINK](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5005.htm#SQLRF01205), or to see the defined db links:

```
SELECT * FROM all_db_links;
```