# What's the meaning of "SELECT * FROM XXX@YYY.XXX" query in Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have recently come across the following oracle query -

```
SELECT a.email FROM info@jellyfish.group a, subscriber b
   WHERE a.email = b.user_name;
```

I am not able to figure out what does **info@jellyfish.group** mean in this query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of '@' symbol in Oracle SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296263/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: [Also relevant?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36339271/266304)

Answer (score 2):

It's (table|view|materialized_view)@(dblink). This part is a query_table_expression: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2126073

Also from the docs: "A database link is a connection between two physical database servers that allows a client to access them as one logical database."

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is (table|view|materialized_view)@(dblink).

If we have to access table from other database we have to create DBLINK to access them.

For all DBLINK information you can find from, 
select * from dba_db_links;