# How can I convert a small query from SQL Server to Oracle, I don't know how to apply their equivalents in reserved words?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have always worked with SQL Server and now I want to learn Oracle, how can I convert this little query from SQL Server to Oracle?

I have errors in this query:

```
with cte as, OFFSET @start ROWS FETCH ,
and exists(select 1 from cte where cte.id_city = h.id_city),
(dateadd(second, h.days, h.datehome) >= @from and dateadd(second, h.days, h.datehome) <= @to)
```

I don't know what the Oracle equivalent will be.

This is my full query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE PKG_HOME AS 

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_HOME_DATA (
from            in timestamp,
to              in timestamp,
start           number,                
page            number    
)                          


AS
BEGIN   
 
    with cte as (
            select   isnull(h.id_city,'') as id_city
                     from main_bdd.home h  
                     left join second_bdd.owner.clients cl on cl.idHome = h.idHome                  
                     where ((dateadd(second, h.days, h.datehome) >= @from and dateadd(second, h.days, h.datehome) <= @to))
                     order by h.datehome asc                 
                     OFFSET @start ROWS FETCH NEXT @page ROWS ONLY
        )

        select 
         
                     isnull(h.id_city,'') as id_city
                     isnull(h.last_ubication,'') as last_ubication            
                     from main_bdd.home h  
                     left join second_bdd.owner.clients cl on cl.idHome = h.idHome 
                     where ((dateadd(second, h.days, h.datehome) >= @from and dateadd(second, h.days, h.datehome) <= @to))
                     AND exists(select 1 from cte where cte.id_city = h.id_city)
                     order by h.datehome asc 
END; 
END PKG_HOME;
```

Comment: I recommend starting with smaller pieces of code.  Separate you code into smaller questions and post those to get your answers.  

I obviously see that you are creating an Oracle package. If you are utilizing Oracle Packages (which you should oracle packages are fantastic and I very much wish they existed in SQL Server)... 

When using a package you simply Declare your procedures, functions, types and Cursors etc... but you don't CREATE them.  If you want to CREATE a Proc or a Function that is not in a package but similar to SQL Server that would be the syntax to create stand alone objects

Comment: Also.. Oracle does not use @ symbols.  Not in the manner that you are trying to use them.  SQL Server uses the @ symbols in the manner I see in your SQL. --- 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296263/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-oracle-sql

Comment: I've been spending the last 2.5 years learning SQL Server after having worked with Oracle for 8 years.

Comment: How could I write these lines of code to their oracle equivalent?
-  with cte as (
-OFFSET start ROWS FETCH NEXT page ROWS ONLY
-AND exists(select 1 from cte where cte.id_city = h.id_city)

Comment: Oracle doesn't ERROR when adding/keeping ORDER BYs.  So silly that when writing SQL in SQL Server... If I just so happen to leave an ORDER BY in my sub query or derived table SQL SERVER starts yelling at me winning and tells me I need to remove it.  I wish I could just tell SQL Server to just ignore it... who cares if there is an order by in there... if you don't like it just ignore it... but alas SQL Server doesn't hear me when I yell at it for doing silly things.

Comment: You are missing a comma in you exterior SELECT clause.  Aside form that, what's the exact error messages you are receiving?

Comment: in this part it tells me: an into statement is expected in this select statement

CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE PKG_HOME AS 

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_HOME_DATA (
from            in timestamp,
to              in timestamp,
start           number,                
page            number    
)                          
AS
BEGIN
WITH cte AS(
            SELECT  id FROM home
            )
SELECT id FROM cte;
How can I fix the problem?

more precisely the error throws me in this line
WITH cte AS

Comment: You can't just `select` in PL/SQL, the language exists for you to process the data somehow - insert into a table, fetch into a variable and check the value, populate an array, something like that. If you want a report you can write a SQL query.

Comment: I'm starting to understand, so when I work with cte I must insert the information, for example, in a temporary table and then execute the select statement. in sql server a temporary table is not necessary and for that reason my confusion
thanks william

Comment: I already solved the errors but now it appears:
subprogram or cursor 'string' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body.

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like (although `second_bdd.owner.clients` looks wrong as it should be `schema_name.table_name` and not `schema_name.table_name.something_else`):

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE PKG_HOME AS
PROCEDURE SP_HOME_DATA (
  i_from   IN  timestamp,
  i_to     IN  timestamp,
  i_start  IN  number,                
  i_page   IN  number,
  o_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
);
END PKG_HOME;
/
```

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE BODY PKG_HOME AS
PROCEDURE SP_HOME_DATA (
  i_from   IN  timestamp,
  i_to     IN  timestamp,
  i_start  IN  number,                
  i_page   IN  number,
  o_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)                          
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_cursor FOR
  with cte as (
    SELECT h.id_city
    FROM   main_bdd.home h  
           left join second_bdd.owner.clients cl
           on cl.idHome = h.idHome                  
    WHERE  h.day + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * h.datehome
             BETWEEN i_from AND i_to
    ORDER BY h.datehome asc                 
    OFFSET i_start ROWS FETCH NEXT i_page ROWS ONLY
  )
  SELECT h.id_city,
         h.last_ubication
  FROM   main_bdd.home h  
         LEFT JOIN second_bdd.owner.clients cl
         on cl.idHome = h.idHome 
  WHERE  h.day + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * h.datehome
             BETWEEN i_from AND i_to
  AND    EXISTS(
           select 1 from cte where cte.id_city = h.id_city
         )
  order by h.datehome asc;
END; 
END PKG_HOME;
/
```

*Note: In Oracle `''` and `NULL` are identical so using `COALESCE(value, '')` (the Oracle equivalent of the `ISNULL` function) is identical to `value` without any wrapped function.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e5c3ba8f0a40107fa2426a3c22f910e3)*